# Error log on Web Service

Tags: c#, web-services, error-log

I have a .NET web service that returns a xml and I want to add an error log class with a method where I can store log messages that I'm adding all over the main code and in the case of an eventual exception send this log as an xml.
I assume I'd need a method to add the string and a method to serialize. Can I have any documentation on how to do the second one?
All I have found is another kind of log technics.

Comment: it's not that difficult to add code to do logging to your web service can you show us what you have tried on your own..? also there are plenty of working examples all over the web as well as here on `SO` on how to do this do a google search on `C# Log Errors in Web Service`

Comment: Why dont you just create a ErrorResponse object with message property, and return the error inside that. Depending on how you built the web service, .NET will already do the serialization of the objects for you.